# C++ Inverting all bits in a fstream

Tags: c++

The title is my question - how would I go about flipping all the bits in an std::ifstream that's been loaded from a file?

```
ifstream file( "filename.png" );

if ( !file.is_open( ) ) {
    return false;
}
```

I don't know how I should be going from here. By flipping, I'm referring to inverting the bits (0 if 1, 1 if 0)

Comment: First read some bytes independent of the flipping, the flip each byte in a loop independent from the file. Where´s the problem?

Comment: have you tried anything beyond opening a file?

Comment: @ What do you mean _"how would I go about flipping all the bits"_ flipping  the bits actually? [`std::ifstream::clear()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear)?

Comment: @deviantfan I'm not quite accustomed to file handling - I posted the question looking for guidance. Could you post some code if you find this so simple?

Comment: @RedAlert As I've just posted to deviantfan, I'm not accustomed to file handling - no, I haven't been able to get any further because I don't know where I should be headed.

Comment: I don't quite understand the downvotes - I'm asking the question because I haven't been able to find a similar question previously posted.

Comment: @dk123 http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/ etc.etc. There are so many examples in the internet, just use Google a bit.

Comment: Do you mean you want to read in data with all the bits flipped? Why do you need to do this in the stream opposed to after you read the data? BTW the answer is: No, standard streams don't have a way to invert all bits on their data because this functionality makes no sense to most people. It's not like it's not possible though.

Comment: Do you really want to invert the bits of a png image? Remember that no existing program will be able to read the image until you flip it back..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an X-Y problem.  I really doubt you want to flip all the bits in a PNG format file, simply because there are other fields in the file besides the bitmap bits.  Also, unless the image is pure black & white, there is more to the color bits than inverting the bits.

That said, here's how to flip the bits.

```
While not the end of the file, do:  
  read a block of bytes (uint8_t)  
  for each byte read do:  
     read the byte  
     invert the byte (a.k.a. using `~` operator)  
     store the byte  
  end-for  
  write block to new file.  
end-while
```

**Side effects of inverting pixels**
Most images are made up of pixels, or picture elements.  These elements are usually represented by a number of bits per pixel and if multiple colors, bits per color.

Let us take for example an RGB image with 24 bits per pixel.  This means that there are 8 bits to represent the red, 8 bits for green and 8 bits for blue.  Each color has a value range of 0 to 255.  This represents the amount of color.

Let us take 1 color, green, with a value of 0x55 or in binary 0101 0101.  Inverting (flipping) the bits will yield a value of 0xAA or 1010 1010.  So after flipping the green value is now 0xAA.

If this is what you want to happen, changing the amount of color on each pixel, then you will need to extract the color quantities from the PNG file for the image and invert them.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::ifstream ifile(argv[1]); /// input
    std::ofstream ofile(argv[2]); /// output

    if (ifile.is_open() && ofile.is_open()) {
        char ch;
        std::string data = "";

        while (ifile.get(ch)) {
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
                ch ^= (1 << i);
            data += ch;
        }
        ofile << data;
    }
    ifile.close();
    ofile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

usage:

```
./prog input output
```

input:

```
$ xxd -b input
0000000: 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110001 00001010
```

output:

```
$ xxd -b output 
0000000: 11001110 11001111 11001111 11001110 11110101
```